# How to check if a json array has a particular value for a key? Angular JS

Tags: javascript

```
 test_array = [  {"id":1,"title":"test1","type":"A"  },  
                 {"id":2,"title":"test2","type":"B"  },  
                 {"id":3,"title":"test3","type":"A"  },
              ]


var x= test_array.isContain("type"=="B")
```

I want a method like I stated above and get an return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
test_array = [  {"id":1,"title":"test1","type":"A"  },  
                 {"id":2,"title":"test2","type":"B"  },  
                 {"id":3,"title":"test3","type":"A"  },
              ]

Array.prototype.isExist = function(key, value){ 
      return this.some(function(obj){ 
          return obj[key] === value;
      });
};

test_array.isExist('type', 'B');
```